# Can't work out why my "unslider" is not working? Fiddle inside

Tags: jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/vqsgkn7e/2/

So I'm not sure why it isn't working. Technically I followed the instructions. Can someone help me out here, and see where I went wrong?

[I'm using this slider](http://unslider.com/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.features').unslider();
});
```

Comment: I get why on-hold, but why did someone just downvote my answer? Or was that automattic...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No JQuery**

In the fiddle you linked, you never defined a library.

This should have been obvious if you were using the dev console, which you ALWAYS should when writing javascript.

Hit F12 and go to console tab (or google your browser name + dev console if F12 does nothing)

**JQuery Selector**

```
$(function() {
    $('#features').unslider();
});
```

NOT

```
$(function() {
    $('.features').unslider();
});
```

This is the wrapper you are targetting, so its an id, not a class

```
<div id="features" class="wrapper">
```

**JQuery Selectors**: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

> https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
>
> Class Selector (“.class”)
>
> Selects all elements with the given class.

---

> https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
>
> ID Selector (“#id”)
>
> Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

**An updated fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/vqsgkn7e/3/

**PS**

Please dont just rely on a fiddle. Fiddles are ALWAYS appreciated, but you really should copy+paste the key code (that js line you pasted, and the targetted html) as that helps alot with quicker answers.

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much.